# Loader: onLoadFinished called only once

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-loader, commonsware-cwac

I have one loader being used in an activity. I'm able to start the loader and it onLoadFinished is called. When I update data and call `onContentChanged` in the loader i see that `loadInBackground` and `deliverResult` are both called. This is where the trail seems to stop. I don't receive any callback to `onLoadFinished`.

If I recreate the activity (aka orientation change, or relaunch) then it will behave the same way.

I'm using the support-v4 loader and loader manager.

My `SharedPreferenceLoader` based on [CommonsWare's loader](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/loaderex/acl/SharedPreferencesLoader.java):

```
public class SharedPreferencesLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<SharedPreferences>
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    private SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    private static final String TAG = SharedPreferencesLoader.class.getSimpleName();

    public SharedPreferencesLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public SharedPreferences loadInBackground() {
        Log.v(TAG, "wol: load in background");
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        return (prefs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (prefs != null) {
            deliverResult(prefs);
        }

        if (takeContentChanged() || prefs == null) {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Log.v(TAG, "wol: on shared preference changed.");
        onContentChanged();
    }
}
```

Here is how the loader is being used:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<SharedPreferences> {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        // fetch list of locations through an intent service.
        // This will save data to shared preferences and trigger onContentChanged
        MyIntentService.startActionGetLocations(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<SharedPreferences> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new SharedPreferencesLoader(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(final Loader<SharedPreferences> sharedPreferencesLoader, final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        final List<PwStructure> locations = SharedPreferencesUtils.getLocations(sharedPreferences, this);
        Log.v(TAG, "wol: on load finished: "+locations);
        /* Do something with data. */
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(final Loader<SharedPreferences> sharedPreferencesLoader) {
    }
}
```

**Update**
I found this in the [LoaderManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.java#352) source. It looks as if the call to `onLoadFinished` isn't called if the data has the same reference.

Comment: +1 for the Update. I was not sure why my onLoadFinished is not called.Thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would appear that with the current LoaderManager implementation, SharedPreferencesLoader is pretty much screwed. I'll deprecate it.

Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Ha! Awesome. Thank you and I appreciate the honesty. I ended up creating a StringPreferenceLoader. This is specific to my needs but it does the job well.
https://github.com/sababado/CustomLoaders